# Issues with Koudoku plan subscription creation on user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using koudoku to accept payment .i have listing and users .Setup koudoku gem as instructed by the guides .

How i can make every user on the app enroll in a plan on sign up(i'm using devise) and send the info to stripe in the same process  , the goal is to have everybody on the free plan and themselves can upgrade in their dashboard?

so far this is what i have and i stuck.
1) create a function "create_subscription" in the subscription model that take parameters from the subscription params hash

```
 class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Koudoku::Subscription

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :coupon

 def create_subscription
    @subscription = subscription.new 
    plan_id = ::Plan.first.id
    subscription.subscription_owner = @owner_id
    subscription.save
    subscription
end
```

end

2)call the function in the devise registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
include ApplicationHelper

 def create
  super 
    @user.create_subscription()
    # Sends email to user when user is created.
    TimarcheMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver 
 end
end
```

in the logs after user creation only one parameter(user_id) was saved in the subscriptions tables

```
  SQL (16.0ms)  INSERT INTO "subscriptions" ("created_at", "updated_at",   "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-05-29 07:26:24.993908"], [
"updated_at", "2015-05-29 07:26:24.993908"], ["user_id", 55]]
```

so far none of the user created have an associated enrollement . any pointers will be helpful.